# Select rows with at least two conditions from all conditions

Tags: r

I have this data frame in R and I need to select only rows that match at least two of the following conditions :

- A >= 5
- B >= 5
- C >= 5
- D >= 5

  ```
            A         B         C         D
  1   0.000000 48.936170  0.000000 29.787234
  2   0.000000 72.340426  0.000000  6.382979 
  3   0.000000 78.723404  0.000000  2.127660
  4   2.127660 78.723404  0.000000  0.000000
  5   0.000000 43.617021  0.000000 35.106383
  6   0.000000 79.787234  0.000000  1.063830
  7   3.191489  0.000000 77.659574  0.000000
  8  77.659574  0.000000  2.127660  0.000000
  9  46.808511  0.000000  0.000000 31.914894
  10 35.106383  0.000000 27.659574  0.000000
  ```

The only solution I found is to use "if"...

```
if ( ((data$A >=5) + (data$B >=5) + (data$C >=5) + (data$D >=5)) >=2 ) {

#result }
```

...but I cannot find how to combine the if selection with my data frame.
I tried like this but I doesn't seem to be the solution for this problem :

```
Selection = data[if ( ((data$A >=5) + (data$B >=5) + (data$C >=5) + (data$D >=5)) >=2 ),]
```

Thanking you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="         A         B         C         D
1   0.000000 48.936170  0.000000 29.787234
2   0.000000 72.340426  0.000000  6.382979 
3   0.000000 78.723404  0.000000  2.127660
4   2.127660 78.723404  0.000000  0.000000
5   0.000000 43.617021  0.000000 35.106383
6   0.000000 79.787234  0.000000  1.063830
7   3.191489  0.000000 77.659574  0.000000
8  77.659574  0.000000  2.127660  0.000000
9  46.808511  0.000000  0.000000 31.914894
10 35.106383  0.000000 27.659574  0.000000")
df[rowSums(df >= 5) >= 2, ]
#           A        B        C         D
# 1   0.00000 48.93617  0.00000 29.787234
# 2   0.00000 72.34043  0.00000  6.382979
# 5   0.00000 43.61702  0.00000 35.106383
# 9  46.80851  0.00000  0.00000 31.914894
# 10 35.10638  0.00000 27.65957  0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! =) (and yes, I changed df > 4 to df >=5)