# Select grouped rows with at least one matching criterion

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select all those groupings that contain at least one of the elements that I am interested in. I was able to do this by creating an intermediate array, but I am looking for something simpler and faster. This is because my actual data set has over 1M rows (and 20 columns) so I am not sure whether I will have sufficient memory to create an intermediate array. More importantly, the below method on my original file takes a lot of time.

Here's my code and data:

a) Data

```
dput(Data_File)
structure(list(Group_ID = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 345, 444, 
444), Product_Name = c("ABCD", "EFGH", "XYZ1", "Z123", "ABCD", 
"EFGH", "ABCD", "ABCD"), Qty = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)), .Names = c("Group_ID", 
"Product_Name", "Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

b) Code: I want to select `Group_ID` that has at least one `Product_Name = ABCD`

```
#Find out transactions
    Data_T <- Data_File %>% 
      group_by(Group_ID) %>%
      dplyr::filter(Product_Name == "ABCD") %>%
      select(Group_ID) %>%
      distinct()

    #Now filter them
    Filtered_T <- Data_File %>% 
      group_by(Group_ID) %>%
      dplyr::filter(Group_ID %in% Data_T$Group_ID)
```

c) Expected output is

```
  Group_ID Product_Name   Qty
     <dbl>        <chr> <dbl>
      123         ABCD     2
      123         EFGH     3
      123         XYZ1     4
      123         Z123     5
      234         ABCD     6
      444         ABCD     8
      444         ABCD     9
```

I'm struggling with this for over 3 hours now. I looked at the auto-suggested thread by SO: [Select rows with at least two conditions from all conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748051/select-rows-with-at-least-two-conditions-from-all-conditions) but my question is very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Data_File %>% group_by(Group_ID) %>%
    filter(any(Product_Name %in% "ABCD"))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# Groups: Group_ID [3]
# 
#   Group_ID Product_Name   Qty
#      <dbl>        <chr> <dbl>
# 1      123         ABCD     2
# 2      123         EFGH     3
# 3      123         XYZ1     4
# 4      123         Z123     5
# 5      234         ABCD     6
# 6      444         ABCD     8
# 7      444         ABCD     9
```

Explanation: `any()` will return `TRUE` if there are any rows (within the group) that match the condition. The length-1 result will then be recycled to the full length of the group and the entire group will be kept. You could also do it with `sum(Product_name %in% "ABCD") > 0` as the condition, but the any reads very nicely. Use `sum` instead if you wanted a more complicated condition, like 3 or more matching product names.

I prefer`%in%`to `==` for things like this because it has better behavior with `NA` and it is easy to expand if you wanted to check for any of multiple products by group.

---

If speed and efficiency are an issue, `data.table` will be faster. I would do it like this, which relies on a keyed join for the filtering and uses no non-data.table operations, so it should be very fast:

```
library(data.table)
df = as.data.table(df)
setkey(df)
groups = unique(subset(df, Product_Name %in% "ABCD", Group_ID))
df[groups, nomatch = 0]
#    Group_ID Product_Name Qty
# 1:      123         ABCD   2
# 2:      123         EFGH   3
# 3:      123         XYZ1   4
# 4:      123         Z123   5
# 5:      234         ABCD   6
# 6:      444         ABCD   8
# 7:      444         ABCD   9
```

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your help. This works well but do you know whether I can do this by using data.table? I am a beginner, and I read that data.table is generally faster than dplyr. Is that right? If so, I'd appreciate your help. I am asking this because I am also looking for memory efficiency and speed. I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: @watchtower :check if this works for you :

dt=data.table(Data_File);    dt[, x1:=ifelse(any(Product_Name %in% "ABCD"), T,F),by = c("Group_ID")];      subset(dt,dt$x1)[,1:3,with=F]

Comment: @watchtower You can also use `dplyr` operations on `data.table` objects to get (usually) 80%-90% of the speed-up you would get using pure data table.