# subset by at least two out of multiple conditions

Tags: r, subset

I found many questions dealing with subsetting by multiple conditions, but just couldn't find how to subset by *at least two* out of >2 conditions.

This SO question deals with the same problem, but applies the same condition to all columns:
[Select rows with at least two conditions from all conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748051/select-rows-with-at-least-two-conditions-from-all-conditions)

My question is: How can I subset rows by at least two out of three different conditions?

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
V1<-c(2,4,4,9,7)
V2<-c(10,20,20,30,20)
V3<-c(0.7,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.9)
df<-data.frame(cbind(id,V1,V2,V3))
```

I can subset rows that meet all three out of three conditions by looping through like this:

```
#empty "subset" data.frame
subdf <- cbind(as.character(),as.numeric(),as.numeric(),as.numeric())
colnames(subdf) <- colnames(df)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df$V1[i] <= 4 && df$V2[i] >= 20 && df$V3[i] <= 0.3)
    subdf <- rbind(subdf,df[i,])
    }
```

Any ideas on how to subset all rows that fulfill either all three, or any combination of two conditions?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension of [LukeA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748104/4895725) there.

```
dfNew <- df[rowSums(cbind(df$V1 <= 4, df$V2 >= 20, df$V3 <= 0.3)) > 1,]
```

which returns

```
dfNew
  id V1 V2  V3
2  2  4 20 0.1
3  3  4 20 0.5
4  4  9 30 0.2
```

The idea is to construct a matrix of the logical vectors with `cbind`and then use `rowSums` to count the number of TRUE values for each row. The rows of the data.frame can then be subset based on this criterion.

Comment: thanks a lot @lmo, this solution is simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick to do something similar. See if you like it. 
The approach is to convert the conditions into text and use `eval`

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
V1<-c(2,4,4,9,7)
V2<-c(10,20,20,30,20)
V3<-c(0.7,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.9)
df<-data.frame(cbind(id,V1,V2,V3))

tests<- c("df$V1 <= 4","df$V2 >= 20" ,"df$V3 <= 0.3")

tests
res<- sapply(tests,FUN = function(txt){eval(parse(text=txt))} )
apply(res,1,sum)
df[apply(res,1,sum) >=2,]
```

Comment: Thanks! For the record, is there any situation in which you would recommend this solution over the above solution shown by lmo?

Comment: The functions I use are much more complex than gt lt comparisons.